# Group of References

Tags: entities

i am working on a site for a association with employees (mostly voluntary) on three "Levels":

1. Nation wide
2. Districts
3. Local

The locals are bound to a district.

The positions for the employees are almost the same on all levels.

- Person1 -> PR nation wide (like a manager for the districts and locals)
- Person2 -> PR in the district
- Person3 -> local PR

The positions should have a kind of priority so that for example the leading person should be on the top of every listing of nation/district/local.

I created 3 content types for NATION, DISTRICT, LOCAL. LOCAL with an entity reference to DISTRICT. And because the listings should be sorted by the priority, I created a JOB content type.

Another content type I created is the PERSON.  Now here is the problem: a PERSON can have more than one position and that could be twice (or 3,4,5...) in a LOCAL or LOCAL and DISTRICT....
So that the position he is having should be group of references (NATION/DISTRICT/LOCAL & JOB).

The thing is that I want to see all the persons working for NATION/DISTRICT/LOCAL (simple view)

A view listing all LOCALS bound to a DISTRICT.

PROBLEM: A listing of all JOBs and places (NATION/DISTRICT/LOCAL) a PERSON is having.

Edit: Drupal 7

Comment: Could you let us know which version of Drupal you're using (in the title or through a tag?).  Views are very different in Drupal 6 and Drupal 7, so being specific always helps!

Answer (score 0):

So to set up the view that displays all jobs and levels a person has, you just have to use the correct relationships in your view.  So if a job is already listed as 'local' or 'regional' by containing **a reference field** (entity or node reference) to the correct level, you can get to that in a view by making sure the view is created as a listing of jobs.

So if you are doing a 'Jobs' listing, set up a filter under the 'Advanced' section to be able to filter by person.  If the 'Person' content type has a field that's a reference to this 'job' content, you should be able to add a '**reverse** reference' in the '**Relationships**' section, so you can filter on that (the Person) to limit the jobs to just a particular person.  You can set that up as a regular filter (hard-coded or exposed so anyone looking at the view can change it) or as a contextual filter that's based on the current person logged in or the person whose profile is being viewed.

Then you can, with each job that pops up in the view, after you've filtered by person, simply display the 'level', since I'm assuming the job will have the level as a reference field already.  You should be able to easily and without any more relationships display all the fields that are associated with the job, such as the job's level.

Does that help at all?  Or did I misunderstand your question?

Comment: I haven't worked with **Relationships** yet but i got it. The thing is that i was thinking about something like a _Local_ having a reference to a _Region_. _job_ is contaning as fields just the name of the job and a number/level for the sorting/priority. And _Person_ should be the content type containing a reference to a _Region_ or _Local_ AND a reference to a job he/she has (can be more than 1). Because all the jobs will sum up to around 30 positions like PR or SUPPORT as locally or region wide. Otherwise if i reference to _Local_ or _Region_ in _Job_ i have to create about 1000 _Job_ jobs.

Comment: That means that _Job_ is a kind of list of aroud 30 jobs (like PR which is availiable for all Regions/Locals and nation wide) and a number (which will not show up in any listing) just for the sort/priority

Comment: If a person is always local, regional or national, regardless of the number of jobs they have, then you have just have the 'level' be a tag/term field on the person.  But if a person can have multiple jobs, each with a different level, that makes it harder if the level isn't with the job.  Perhaps you can have fields in your 'Person' that are something like '1st Job level', and then '1st Job Reference' (points to the correct job content type).  Then you could repeat that for several more fields?  I'm not sure how else you could structure it actually....

Comment: That is acutally a good idea. Thank you. Though i am not sure, if this ist really going to work fluent with autocomplete field with about 1000 jobs as reference.